# Why does “failing” (from lens) produce invalid traversals?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

From [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.6/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:failing):

> Try the first `Traversal` (or `Fold`), falling back on the second `Traversal` (or `Fold`) if it returns no entries.
>
> This is only a valid `Traversal` if the second `Traversal` is disjoint from the result of the first or returns exactly the same results.

Is there a simple example of an invalid traversal generated by `failing` and a test case demonstrating it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see how this can generate invalid Traversals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the counterexample, let us first define a new data type, for which we generate traversals using `makePrisms`:

```
data T = A T | C deriving Show
makePrisms ''T
```

`_A :: Traversal T T` is now a valid traversal. Now, construct a new traversal using `failing`:

```
t :: Traversal' T T
t = failing _A id
```

Notice that `(C & t .~ A C) ^.. t = [C]`, which looks like it fails a traversal law (you don't "get what you put in"). Indeed, the second traversal law is:

```
fmap (t f) . t g ≡ getCompose . t (Compose . fmap f . g)
```

which is not satisfied, as can be seen with the following choice for `f` and `g`:

```
-- getConst . t f = toListOf t
f :: T -> Const [T] T
f = Const . (:[])

-- runIdentity . t g = t .~ A C
g :: T -> Identity T
g = pure . const (A C)
```

Then:

```
> getConst . runIdentity . fmap (t f) . t g $ C
[C]
```

While:

```
> getConst . runIdentity . getCompose . t (Compose . fmap f . g) $ C
[A C]
```

So there is indeed a case where `failing` with valid traversals doesn't produce a valid traversal.